# Epoxy inlay on gel stained desktop

Tags: staining, epoxy

I am building a small desktop for my son. He wants it gray so I am using poplar with a General Finishes gel stain.

I am going to CNC his initials on top and then pour an epoxy in there for an inlay.

My question is, if I gel stain after sanding down the epoxy will any if the stain stick to the epoxy? I do not want that.

Or am I just missing an obvious solution here in my order of work.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I would have used the dupe target's target to close this one to avoid the extra click, but we'll get there in the end...

Comment: I read both of those prior to submitting and didn't seem to find a clear answer as to "will gel stain stick to epoxy"

Comment: Gel stain doesn't bond well to epoxy, unless the epoxy has a distinct texture (e.g. sanding scratches); it is texture like this that allows a subsequent finish to literally grab on to what's below. But this assumes it's applied and not disturbed. Since the standard application for "gel stain" includes a wiping-off stage that's your opportunity to remove the gel from the epoxy (if necessary using Q-tips or whatever.... it'll take as long as it takes). Just in case it wasn't stated outright in what you've read up to this point, you're going to need to apply a topcoat over the "gel stain".